# Function on Cantor set

Tags: cantor-set

Let $C$ is a classical Cantor set. Can we find a number $\alpha>1$ and non-constant function $f: C\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le 2000|x-y|^\alpha, \ \forall x,y\in C.$$.

It will be great if someone give me a tip.

Comment: Are you sure about your question? $f(x) = x$ and $\alpha = 1$ trivially works

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Small mistake, but important. Condition $\alpha>1$

Comment: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &, x \leqslant \frac{1}{3} \\ 1 &, x \geqslant \frac{2}{3}.\end{cases}$$